# getting full working single page with phantomjs

Tags: phantomjs

I'm trying to get this page: http://www.pqllana.com.ar/distribuidores/mapa with phantomjs.
I have special interest in getting the section that contains "ubicacion", "locales", "mapa".
As you can see in the page, it works with javascript, and I want to get those sections fully working, I mean that if I click on them they should work as expected.

What happens is that the google map is not loaded correctly, and some links doesn't work at all. I'm retrieving the page using this code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://www.pqllana.com.ar/distribuidores/mapa', function() {
  var content = page.content;

  var fs = require('fs');
   try {
    fs.write("hellohello.ctp", content, 'w');
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }


  phantom.exit();
});
```

What I do is I pick that file and render into another page.

Comment: What do you want ultimately to achieve? Why don't you render the page instead of trying to write the contents into a file?

Comment: I have two pages: "A" and "B".
"A" contains a section that uses databases and javascript, it basically picks information from a database and you can play with that info online thanks to the javascript code. "A" of course is online.

"B" is another page, and my idea is to pick a full working section from "A" and render it into "B" (and be able to interact with the information in the same way)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what I'm trying to achieve is not possible with PhantomJS (not suitable for this task), so I'm going to implement an iFrame, deactivate it's scrollbar and use dynamic size.